# Theorem about monochromatic cycles

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple directed graph that every arrow is colored with black or pink. If $G$ has monochromatic cycle then $G$ has a simple monochromatic cycle. How to prove that theorem?

monochromatic cycle is a cycle which is colored with one color only.

How should I prove this theorem?

I have a hinche that we need to look at the subpath of the cycle and find out that it's also a simple cycle (but how). In that way we will get a monochromatic simple cycle because its a subpath of the monochromatic cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the cycle visits some intermediate vertex more than once.  If we omit the portion of the path between the first and second visit, we still have a monochromatic cycle, but it's shorter than the original one.

From this observation, you should have no trouble constructing a proof.